# Replace character in a string using RegEx JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a number of inputs names with last digit changing:

```
<input name="ProductsLang[1][text][0]">
<input name="ProductsLang[1][text][1]">
<input name="ProductsLang[1][text][2]">
```

I'm adding new inputs dynamically and I need to recalculate all indexes accordingly due to I might add one in between. So I have a small function with regex to replace them:

```
$('input').each(function(i) {
    var matches = $(this).attr('name').match(/ProductsLang\[\d+\]\[[^\]]+\]\[(\d+)\]/);
    var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace(matches[1], i);
    $(this).attr('name', newName);
});
```

and it works weird... instead of changing last digit I can get a result like this:

```
<input name="ProductsLang[1][text][0]">
<input name="ProductsLang[1][text][1]">
<input name="ProductsLang[2][text][1]">
<input name="ProductsLang[1][text][3]">
```

Why does replace works like that? Help me figure it out. All I need is to increment last digit.

Comment: Try just `$(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\[\d+]$/, '[' + i + ']'));` instead of the 3 lines inside `each`.

Comment: Thanks, its works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the body of your `.each` with this line

```
$(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\[\d+]$/, '[' + i + ']'));
```

The `/\[\d+]$/` pattern matches a `[`, 1 or more digits and then a `]` *at the end of the string* (due to the [`$` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)).

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/TC49SY/1).